# Print repeated letters in C++

Tags: c++, string, for-loop

I want to write a program where I print repeated letters. Here I have code, but it print whole word for me. Can You give me some advice?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main(){
string slowo, temp, temp2;

cout << "Insert word: ";
cin >> word;

for(int i = 0; i <= word.length(); i++){
    temp = word[i];

    for(int j = 1; j < word.length(); j++){
        temp2 = word[j];

        if(temp == temp2)
            cout << temp2;
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please show what you use for input, what you expect as output and what you get for output.

Comment: e.g. input: printer
output: r

Comment: But what is the output if the input is: "aaaabbbb" ?

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i <= word.length(); i++)` is past the end of the string, should be `i < word.length()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, no need to have the temporary std::string variables:

```
// ...
```

UPDATE As the commenters mentioned correctly, the above will print the characters repeatedly so here is a fix for that:

```
std::cout << "Insert word: ";

std::string word;
std::cin >> word;

std::set<char> repeated;
for (auto i = 0; i < word.length(); ++i) {
    for (auto j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
        if (word[j] == word[i]) {
            if (repeated.find(word[i]) == repeated.end()) {
                repeated.insert(word[i]);
                std::cout << word[i];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but if the input is: "aaaa" you will print: "aaaaaa"

Comment: `set::insert` returns (in part) a `bool` to indicate whether the insertion succeeded, so you can avoid a search followed by an insert with something like: `if (word[j] == word[i] && repeated.insert(word[i]).second) std::cout << word[i];`

Answer (score 2):

1. `for(int i = 0; i <= word.length(); i++){`
   should be `i < word.length()` (out of range)
2. `for(int j = 1; j < word.length(); j++){`
   would work better with `for(int j = i + 1; ...` I guess.

Besides, `temp` and `temp2` is enough to be `char` (you are constructing new strings which is not necessary).

Note however, that either this or the accepted solution will output the letters multiple times if they repeat more than once. E.g. the word "reparature" will output the letter 'r' three times. If you only need to output each repeated letter once, you'll need to track which letters you already wrote out, for example by std::map (or unordered_map with C++11).

Also, then you can actually process the word in O(n) (with std::unordered_map) or O(n * log n) (with std::map) instead of O(n^2) (the current solution).

Here how to do that in O(n) (amortized):

```
unordered_map<char, int> mem;
for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++){
    const char c = word[i];
    if (mem[c]++ == 1)
       cout << c;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one example to do what you want:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    string word, temp, temp2;
    set<char> letters;

    cout << "Insert word: ";
    cin >> word;

    for (auto letter1: word) {
        int match = 0;
        for (auto letter2: word) {
            if (letter1 == letter2)
                match++;
            if (match > 1)
                letters.insert(letter1);
        }
    }

    cout << "\nRepeated letters found:\n";
    for (auto letter:letters)
        cout << letter << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Results when running it:

```
Insert word: anaconda

Repeated letters found:
a
n
```

Comment: But this is still O(n^2) - with set or map the word can be processed in O(n * logn) (without the inner loop).